# HttpPostAsync not returning any result but inserting entity correctly

Tags: c#, api, http, xamarin, .net-5

I have a generic `PostAsync` method and then I have my `AddCart` method to insert my `CrCart` entity on my api. The thing is, I want to return the result but it will stop and not return anything even though it is inserting on the api correctly.

Here is my `PostAsync` method

```
 // Generic Post Method
        public async Task<T> HttpPostAsync<T>(string url, string token, T data)
        {
            T result = default(T); // résultat de type générique

            try
            {
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
                StringContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResponse);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(((int)response.StatusCode).ToString() + " - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnError(ex.ToString());
                return result;
            }
        }
```

And here is my `AddCart` method

```
public async Task<CrCart> AddCart(string url, string token, CrCart data)
        {

            var cart = await _apiService.HttpPostAsync(url, token, data);

            return cart;

        }
```

This is where I call `AddCart`. It is called the same.

```
        private async void AddCart()
        {
            if (CurrentPropertiesService.GetCart() == "" )
            {
                _oCart = new CrCart()
                {
                    IdCustomer = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentPropertiesService.GetCustomer()),
                    IdUser = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentPropertiesService.GetUserId()),
                    Date = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    Status = "Saved"
                };

                var cart = await _apiService.AddCart(Constants.UrlCart, CurrentPropertiesService.GetToken(), _oCart);
                CurrentPropertiesService.SaveCart(cart);
            }
            else
            {
                _oCart.Id = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentPropertiesService.GetCart());
            }

        }
```

Then I call that method on my constructor. And that is all the call stack.

```
public ProductDetailPage(CrProduct oProduct, int category)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _oProduct = oProduct;

            ProductImage.Source = _oProduct.Image;
            txtName.Text = _oProduct.Name;
            txtDescription.Text = _oProduct.Description;
            txtDetails.Text = _oProduct.Stock.ToString();
            txtPrice.Text = string.Format("{0:N2}€", _oProduct.Price.ToString());
            AddCart();
        }
```

When I try to debug it stops as I said in this line, inserts correctly and doesn't give any errors but doesn't return response.

```
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content);
```

I tried calling it on the OnAppearing() method instead of the constructor and making it async to see if that made any difference but doesn't work either.

Please help because I don't know what is the issue here. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you have an async deadlock? Is the call stack (HttpPostAsync, AddCart, the caller of AddCart, etc.) async using `await` all the way up the chain?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Yes, I am using await in all. I will add the line where I call `AddCart` method.

Comment: So there's no `.Result` or `.Wait();` code anywhere in the call stack?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar No, that's all. I will add the full code of the method where I call `AddCart` which is called `AddCart` too.

Comment: @Abed What difference do you feel that will make? `PostAsync` just uses `SendAsync` internally anyway.

Comment: The bug is using `async void`. Such a method can't be awaited so its caller may exit before that method had a chance to finish. You *can't* use asynchronous methods in a constructor they way you did, unless you explicitly block them. Another option is to *store* the async task in a field and await it the first time you need to use the result. Another option is to extract that asynchronous operation and create the new object when it finishes. Yet another is to create a Factory method that produces these values asynchronously instead of using the constructor

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos As I said I tried to use OnAppearing() method to call my `AddCart` method instead of doing it in the constructor but made no difference. I can't do that either?

Comment: You can, but the results will still appear only when the method completes. Instead of trying to mix presentation and data though, you should investigate patterns like [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm), which is *very* popular in Xamarin Forms. The data you're loading is the Model, your page is the View. Instead of trying to load the data directly and modify the UI, have the controls bind to a ViewModel/DTO and use a task to load the new ViewModel and replace the old one. The View will update itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I want to try and use the MVVM pattern but I need to have this done first. I still get no result by calling it on the `OnAppearing` method. Also the AddCart method has nothing to do with what I am loading on my view.

Comment: I already explained why this happens and why you need to use data binding instead. Using `async void OnAppearing` doesn't mean the results will be available right after the form appears. They'll appear once they're returned by the remote service. When that happens, the code after `await` can update any UI elements. The form won't remain hidden until `OnAppearing` completes.

Comment: Instead of manually modifying the components though, you can use data binding to have them display the contents of properties. This way, when the property values change and `INotifyPropertyChanged` is raised, the components will redraw themselves using the new values.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm sorry but I don't understand how I can call this method with data binding and not get this error. I haven't used MVVM architecture before and english is not my first language sorry.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I searched about MVVM and I still don't know how to call void method on my view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in first comment, this is probably a deadlock.

This simple fix might do what you need:

```cs
public ProductDetailPage(CrProduct oProduct, int category)
{
    ...
    // Create an "async" context on MainThread. Code inside runs AFTER constructor returns.
    // Can also use the equivalent Xamarin.Essentials.MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread.
    Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        await AddCart();
    }
}
```

NOTE: I am deliberately NOT using the newer `MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync`, because constructor is not an `async` method.

IMPLICATION: Because this code runs slightly later, the page might first appear without any cart contents. If so, then avoiding that requires changing code elsewhere - where the constructor is called. But first, see if the above works.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked! I am going to try know and change the code elsewhere. Again thanks!

Answer (score -1):

According to your description, the await method `var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content);` post the entity correctly but the `response` is null.

So the cause may be the method is an asynchronous method, and the program go to the next line  `if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)` without waiting the result of the `await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content);`.

You can try to use the following code to make the program wait the PostAsync:

```
var response = httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content).Wait
or
var response = httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content).Result
```

Comment: Sorry, but your analysis is not correct. Its **impossible** for `var response = await ...` to "go to the next line without waiting the result". That's not how async/await works.

Comment: Genuine knowledge comes from practice. But op didn't reply to me, you are right. @ToolmakerSteve